# Uncaught ReferenceError:switchEditors is not defined

Tags: errors, tinymce

Is anyone familiar with this error?  It is causing TinyMCE to break in my Wordpress theme.

In console it gives me these two errors both seem to originate from wp-admin/post-new.php

> Uncaught ReferenceError:switchEditors is not defined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function /wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,…editor,quickt&load%5B%5D=ags,wplink,wp-fullscreen,media-upload&ver=3.9.1:2

[image]

Both the Visual and Smart tabs break, becoming unclickable, and the TinyMCE toolbar disappears.

Comment: I have this issue, and it looks like the ACF Repeater Field plugin is part of the problem. Haven't been able to resolve it yet though...

Answer (score 4):

it might me entirely different solution that i am providing but it solved the problem for me.

I followed these steps:

1. Open the user that is getting error. (Wordpress admin menu > users > your profile)
2. Changed the setting of "Disable the visual editor when writing" and saved the settings
3. Again disabled this feature and saved the settings
4. Boom. my editor is back.

Maybe it could solve someone else problem.

Regards,

Rao

Comment: Worked for me but i don't understand what actually have happen.

Comment: Worked for me either.

Comment: Thats pretty crazy, worked for me too. But oh boi, i dont understand why...

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably having a conflict with some plugin or the theme (bad javascript usually). If you got some kind of an adblocker, this might be another reason too, so you'd better check them all and see if it is a browser-sensitive problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable concatenation by defining `CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS` constant to false. In `wp-config.php` would be fitting:

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

W3TC shouldn't affect anything on admin side.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue - I added this line to the bottom of wp-config.php and BOOM!

define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);